# Disable update notifier

Tags: updates, update-manager, notification, 21.10

I'm trying to disable the update notifier completely. Unfortunately the GUI options does not allow this.

I found this hint:

```
$ sudo apt purge update-notifier update-notifier-common
```

but it asks for the removal also of:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ttf-mscorefonts-installer* ubuntu-desktop* ubuntu-desktop-minimal*
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk* update-manager* update-notifier*
  update-notifier-common*
```

I'm not sure it's correct to remove, say, `ubuntu-desktop`. In fact:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep ubuntu-desktop
ii  ubuntu-desktop                             1.472                                      amd64        The Ubuntu desktop system
ii  ubuntu-desktop-minimal                     1.472                                      amd64        The Ubuntu desktop minimal system
```

They are the desktop system packages.
Before making a mess in the computer, would you please help me to understand how to get rid of any notifications about updates?

I just want to check and install them manually from command line.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me with 21.10 and 22.04.

UpdateManager is just a python package so you can edit its code. So...

In text editor with root privileges open UpdateManager.py

```
sudo gedit /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdateManager.py
```

In function     **UpdateManager.start_available**
(string # 237)
insert `return` statement, so as the result looks like:

```
def start_available(self, cancelled_update=False, error_occurred=False):
    self._look_busy()
    self.refresh_cache()

    return   # <<<--- added statement

    if self.cache is None:
        return

    pane = self._make_available_pane(self.cache.install_count
                                     + self.cache.del_count,
                                     os.path.exists(REBOOT_REQUIRED_FILE),
                                     cancelled_update, error_occurred)
    self._start_pane(pane)
```

Save the file.

Of course you can revert it back by simply removing or commenting out that `return` statement.

Comment: Wow, we have to hack the Ubuntu code in order to stop spamming updates :)

Comment: Seriously, thanks for the hint. I wonder if I manually trigger an upgrade, it will restore the original code?

Comment: That is an interesting question. Worth a try :)

Answer (score 0):

I have Lubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. The way I disable it is by editing this script as root:

```
/usr/lib/lubuntu-update-notifier/lubuntu-upg-notifier.sh
```

I then added `exit;` after the comments and before other code executed.

However, you'll need to logout and back in again.

I prefer to upgrade my OS the manual way when I feel like it, using apt.